# Laravel Excel "Cannot access offset of type string on string" error during data import

Tags: laravel

I'm currently working on a data import feature using the Laravel Excel package. During the import process, I'm encountering the error message "Cannot access offset of type string on string." I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to resolve this issue.

I have excel data like this.

```
  url                    content_placement_price    article_price long_article
https://web.whatsapp.com/    12                      33          66
```

dd($rows);

```
array:4 [ // app\Imports\DataImport.php:16
  0 => "url"
  1 => "content_placement_price"
  2 => "article_price"
  3 => null
]
```

Here's the relevant code snippet where the error is occurring:

**controller**

```
`public function AddWebsiteListByPublisher(){

    Excel::import(new DataImport(), $this->file);
}`
```

**class DataImport**

class DataImport implements ToModel
{

```
public function model(array $rows)
{
    try {
           
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            
                WlProducts::create([
                    'url' => $row['url'],
                    'content_placement_price' => $row['content_placement_price'],
                    'mini_post_price' => $row['mini_post_price'],
                    'article_price' => $row['article_price'],
                    'long_article' => $row['long_article'],
                ]);
        }

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        // Handle the exception (log, return an error response, etc.)
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: When you do ```dd($row)``` inside your loop, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data from the `dd($rows)` command, your array is not associative. So you can't access your values by the names. Change your code to this:

```
WlProducts::create([
    'url' => $rows[0],
    'content_placement_price' => $rows[1],
    'mini_post_price' => $rows[2],
    'article_price' => $rows[3],
    'long_article' => $rows[4],
]);
```

Comment: i have used this code but data is not inserting into product table but i get status code 200 in response.

Comment: Well that could be another issue now. Are all of your fields listed in the ```$fillable``` array in your ```WlProducts``` model?